# Display Raster Cell Values instead of Colours

Tags: raster, arcmap, labeling, symbology

Im trying to display a raster's values as text within each cell since the spatial resolution is so low. [![As seen here the values for each cell are displayed while the symbology is either transparent, or the only visible colouring is from another layer.][1]][1]
I'm working in ArcMap but so far I can't manage to find anything within the symbology tab to make this happen.
That said I'm sure there is a work-around by converting my raster into a polygon or shapefile to get the values. Open to suggestions though.

Comment: There are many answers on this site on how to do that, for example, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33797/63384, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/89367/63384, and for other software you can have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13153/how-to-label-raster-cells-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299472/63384

Comment: Be careful what you wish for, a million cells would render a million labels...